# How to make an iso from current ubuntu install

Tags: iso, 20.10

It looks like all the answers here are about discontuinued software and I would like to know how to do this in 20.10

Comment: I agree, all the Linux ISO remastering apps seem to have been abandoned. Do you really need an ISO? An image file will do almost everything an ISO will do.and is much simpler. set up a Ubuntu disk as you want it and create an image with Disks. You can then use Rufus, Etcher, mkusb, etc to flash the installed system to another drive. An example of using such an image is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step/1291882#1291882

Comment: OK yeah this shows I don't know what I'm doing in terms of imaging, but I'm still going to keep an eye on this question to see if anyone has further insight on this topic.

Comment: Just use gnome-disks. Click on the drive, click on the gears icon, create a partition image, and you're done. You have a .img file that can be burned/written just like an .iso file. If you want, you can even convert the .img to .iso, but there's probably no need to do so.

Comment: @KGIII  Making an image of a partition will not copy the bootloader, for that you need to make an image of the whole disk, that requires the icon with three lines on the upper right of Disks.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Thanks, I forgot about that bit. It has been a while since I've gone through the process. I should probably do it again on a current Ubuntu just to refresh my memory.

Comment: @KGIII I have just had some success creating a partition image as you suggest and then flashing it to a partition on a different drive and booting it. First I created a `bios_grub` partition then a `boot,esp` partition, (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step/1217839#1217839). After flashing the image file to the new drive I reinstalled GRUB and it booted. I guess there is no need to overwrite the whole drive.

Comment: @captaincooler I have not tried SystemBack ,but have heard that it still works four years after being abandoned: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-systemback-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-18-10

Comment: I use clonezilla

Comment: I'm trying to create a customized installation USB Stick (ie: customized installation iso with prefilled answers for unattended install). This used to be rather easy with previous ubuntu versions (like filling some pressed using debian installer format). But I don't have a clue how to do this starting with the current (Ubuntu 20.10 server) installation disk. Any hint @C.S.Cameron ?

Comment: @kriss, Sorry, I have no experience with unattended install. I should probably learn more about it.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron: I'm slowly figuring it out. I probably should contribute some Q/A if I get it to work.

Comment: @kriss Yes, please do, I have seen quite a few questions about unattended install on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Systemback does still work. So do Clonezilla and Distroshare. There are also paid options. See https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2021/08/17/linux-v2p/#ILa